# Error in Android when attaching a date string to a voice message path

Tags: android, datetime, voice-recording

I receive an error when trying to save a voice message after recording it.
It only happens when I add a dateTime instance added as a string to the voice message path like this: "myRecording 2015 17:33:30.3gp" but never happens when I leave the dateTime instance out. However, I would like to have the dateTime instance added to the path.

My code for setting up the path looks like this:

```
public VoiceRecorder() {

        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());

        String dir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                + "/MyRecordings";

        File newdir = new File(dir);
        if (!newdir.exists())
            newdir.mkdirs();

        filePath = dir + "/myVoiceRecording " + date +".3gp";
    }
```

The error message I receive is:

> QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
>   QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
>   error (1, -2147483648)
>   prepare() failed

I receive this error on the emulator and on my phone.
Since it works when I do not add a dateTime instance, I assume that there is something wrong with the way the final path is interpreted by the media player but I cannot figure out what the issue might be, can anyone here help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems colon ":" is not allowed in the android filesystem.
you can probably do it with underscores

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
Date now = new Date();
String date = formatter.format(now);
...
...
filePath = dir + "/myVoiceRecording" + date +".3gp";
```

Comment: Replacing the colons with underscores worked for me, I used @j2emanue 's solution but with replacing colon instead! 
date = date.replaceAll(":", "_");

Answer (score 1):

the way how you currently have it a call would look like this:
*/storage/emulated/0/Music/MyRecordings/myVoiceRecording Dec 12, 2015 1:08:48 PM.3gp*
Notice the spaces on the date, how do you expect the OS to read the spaces ?
Try creating that on the Linux command line and it will fail.

if you really want to store the date like that instead of timestamp which is the better way by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`

then you will have to replace the spaces with underscores:

try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
//replace spaces with underscores
    date = date.replaceAll(" ", "_");

    String dir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
            + "/MyRecordings";

    File newdir = new File(dir);
    if (!newdir.exists())
        newdir.mkdirs();


   String filePath = dir + "/myVoiceRecording " + date +".3gp";
```